# How to highlight a searched text in vim editor?

Tags: command-line, vim, search, text

I have vim editor version 7.3

However in this when I search for a test by typing `:/SEARCHTEXT` the cursor goes to the line containing the text which is searched, but the text itself is NOT highlighted.

I tried by typing `:hlsearch` but i get an error saying `E492: Not an editor command: hlsearch`

Is this because the vim package I have installed does not support `hlsearch`. If yes then  can anyone please tell me which vim package should i install so that searched text will be highlighted ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an option

open VIM and run

```
:set hlsearch
```

To turn it off

```
:set nohlsearch
```

See http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_all_search_pattern_matches for details

Comment: Thanks. It's working now. I am following a basic linux tutorial pdf. There it was written that `:hlsearch` would do the work. But looks like we need to add `set` before `hlsearch` to make it work.

Comment: you are most welcome

Comment: /search then use n to search to bottom, or N bottom to top